# Applying a mapping function to each member of an ndarray with indices as arguments

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an ndarray representing an RGB image with the shape of (width,height,3) and I wish to replace each value with the result of some function of itself, its position and the color channel it belongs to. Doing so in three nested for loops is extremely slow, is there a way to express this as a native array operation ?

Edit: looking for an in-place solution - one that does not involve creating  another O(width x height) ndarray (unless numpy has some magic that can prevent such ndarray from actually being allocated)

Comment: Depends on the specific funtion you want to apply.  Could you be more specific?

Comment: a lot of functions can be applied directly on the array. You can also use `np.indices(your_array.shape)` to get the index values of your image. What function do you want to apply?

Comment: Ideally I want to apply the result of any python callable but let's say that I want to multiply each channel by a (different) constant multiplied by its (normalized) distance from the center.

Comment: If your function can only work with one element (in the width/height space) at a time, then some sort of Python level iteration is required.  Most of the fast compiled `numpy` operations are mathematically simple ones (e.g. multiplication) that take the whole array(s) and return a new one.  As long as your question remains general, the answers will be general.

Comment: Why are you worried about allocating new (or temporary) arrays?  Do you think that will make the calculations faster?  I sense that you need more experience with basic `numpy` calculations, getting a better sense of the fast and slow ways.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your question correct! What I understood is that you want to apply a mapping on each channel of your RGB image based on their corresponding indices, if so the code below **MIGHT** help, since no details was available in your question.

```
import numpy as np

bit_depth = 8
patch_size = 32    

def lut_generator(constant_multiplier):
    x = np.arange(2 ** bit_depth)
    y = constant_multiplier * x
    return dict(zip(x, y))


rgb = np.random.randint(0, (2**bit_depth), (patch_size, patch_size, 3))
# Considering a simple lookup table without using indices.
lut = lut_generator(5)

# splitting three channels followed and their respective indices.
# You can use indexes wherever you need them.
r, g, b = np.dsplit(rgb, rgb.shape[-1])
indexes = np.arange(rgb.size).reshape(rgb.shape)
r_idx, g_idx, b_idx = np.dsplit(indexes, indexes.shape[-1])

# Apply transformation on each channel.
transformed_r = np.vectorize(lut.get)(r)
transformed_g = np.vectorize(lut.get)(g)
transformed_b = np.vectorize(lut.get)(b)
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Take note of the qualifications in many of the comments, using numpy arithmetic directly will often be easier and faster.

```
import numpy as np

def test(item, ix0, ix1, ix2):
    # A function with the required signature. This you customise to suit.
    return item*(ix0+ix1+ix2)//202

def make_function_for(arr, f):
''' where arr is a 3D numpy array and f is a function taking four arguments.
        item : the item from the array
        ix0 ... ix2 : the three indices
    it returns the required result from these 4 arguments. 
'''
    def user_f(ix0, ix1, ix2):
        # np.fromfunction requires only the three indices as arguments.
        ix0=ix0.astype(np.int32)
        ix1=ix1.astype(np.int32)
        ix2=ix2.astype(np.int32)
        return f(arr[ix0, ix1, ix2], ix0, ix1, ix2)
    return user_f
    # user_f is a function suitable for calling in np.fromfunction

a=np.arange(100*100*3)
a.shape=100,100,3
a[...]=np.fromfunction(make_function_for(a, test), a.shape)
```

My test function is pretty simple so I can do it in numpy.

Using fromfunction:

```
%timeit np.fromfunction(make_function_for(a, test), a.shape)
5.7 ms ± 346 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Using numpy arithmetic:

```
def alt_func(arr):
    temp=np.add.outer(np.arange(arr.shape[0]), np.arange(arr.shape[1]))
    temp=np.add.outer(temp,np.arange(arr.shape[2]))
    return arr*temp//202

%timeit alt_func(a)
967 µs ± 4.94 µs per loop  (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

So numpy arithmetic is almost 6 times as fast on my machine for this case.

Edited to correct my seemingly inevitable typos!